# Executable written in Qt behaves differently on Fedora 16 and 18

Tags: c++, qt, environment

In short, the same executable written in Qt writes out a colourful PDF in one Fedora 16 PC but writes out a grayscale one on another Fedora 18. Are there any environment variables that can affect the colour settings of QPen?

The example program is as follows:

```
#include <QPrinter>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPainter>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv, false);
  QPrinter printer(QPrinter::ScreenResolution);
  printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
  printer.setOutputFileName("test.pdf");
  printer.setPaperSize(QPrinter::A4);  // default A4
  QPainter painter;
  if(!painter.begin(&printer)) return 3;
  QPen pen;
  pen.setColor(Qt::red);
  painter.setPen(pen);
  painter.drawRect(100, 100, 50, 50);
  painter.end();
  return 0;
}
```

On a Fedora 16, it draws a rectangle in red line. However, on another Fedora 18, the rectangle is in gray!

- Fedora 16 uses qt-4.8.4-14.fc17.x86_64
- Fedora 18 uses qt-4.8.4-17.fc18.i686

I even tried copying the executable generated on F18 to F16, it successfully draws a red rectangle.

The only reason I can figure out is that there is a magical environment variable that alters the default behaviour of Qt. However I have no clue which variable it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably due to the setup of the default printer of the respective system (my guess). If you want to force it to color, use [QPrinter::setColorMode](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprinter.html#setColorMode).

Comment: Fantastic! This is indeed the reason. Once I change my default printer from a grayscale laser printer to PDFWriter, the colors come back. So the best and safest way to ensure it is to explicitly set ColorMode to QPrinter::Color. Thanks for the help!